# Firebase cloud storage only on production not working

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a project currently working on local to upload files, images and video and all works perfectly.

If i execute `ng serve --configuration=development` all works good,

but if i do `ng serve --configuration=production` then it doesn't work, like it doesn't initialize the cloud storage.

And it says

> Service storage is not available

when i try to inject my custom service using the cloud storage in my constructor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, uploadBytes, ref, getBytes, getDownloadURL } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseStorageService {

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }
}
```

I've tried changing links in the environments, but the 2 environments are actually the same, i tried with the production API using ng serve dev and it works perfectly and i can upload images, but i have this app builded as production and uploaded to my VPS cloud server.

Comment: what angular and firebase version you are using?

Comment: i'm using angular 15, and     "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "firebase": "^10.8.1",

Comment: i deleted the package-lock.json and reinstall dependecies removing firebase one and it works

Comment: nice to know that and it will be better if you please post it as your own answer